# how to connect p2p connection using jgroup for external network

Tags: java, tcp, udp, jgroups

I am using Jgroups for my application and running a simple chat application of JGroups demo but not able to run the application with the external network.

I am using this command for connecting p2p. I'm able to connect the application in the same network p2p but not connecting different networks

java -Djgroups.bind_addr=internal ip -Djoups.external_addr=external ip -Djgroups.TCPPING.initial_hosts=external ip -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true SimpleChat.

Answer (score 0):

`joups.external_addr` is misspelled: it needs to be `jgroups.external_addr`. Ditto for TCPPING: `-Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts`. The latter also needs to have a comma-separated list of IP addresses *and ports*, e.g. `host1[7800],host2[7800]`. The `bind_port` attribute (`7800`) needs to be set in the transport (e.g. `TCP`)

Comment: Thanks Bela Ban for your reply, but still it's not connecting. Firewall is off in both the systems in the different networks. 

java -Djgroups.bind_addr=my_private_ip -Djgroups.bind_port=7800 -Djgroups.tcpping.intial_hosts=your_publicip[port] -Djgroups.external_port=external_port -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true SimpleChat